# Find local extrema of the function.

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following function and I want to find its local extremas:

$f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2-15x-12y+4$

Is it correct? Wolphram alpha says that the only solutions are **-24** and **32** I am little bit confused.

I have done the following calculations:

$\nabla f(x,y)=[3x^2+3y^2-15,6xy-12]$

$\nabla f(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} 3x^2+3y^2-15=0 \\6xy-12=0 \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases} 3x^2+3y^2-15=0 \\6xy-12=0 \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases} x=\frac 2y \\  \frac{12}{y^2} + 3y^2 -15 =0 \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} x=\frac 2y \\  \frac{4+y^4-5y^2}{y^2} =0 \end{cases}  $

$y\neq0$

$4+y^4-5y^2 = 0$

lets substitute $y^2=r$

$r^2-5r+4=0$

$r1=1$
$r2=4$

So there are 4 solutions

$y=1 \lor y=-1 \lor y=2 \lor y=-2$

$\begin{cases} y=1 \\ x=2 \end{cases}$
$\begin{cases} y=-1 \\ x=-2 \end{cases}$
$\begin{cases} y=2 \\ x=1 \end{cases}$
$\begin{cases} y=-1 \\ x=-2 \end{cases}$

There are 4 local extremas :
**-24** minimum
**32** maximum
**-22** minimum
**30** maximum

Comment: Wolfram, please.

Comment: WA is giving you the *global* extrema.

Comment: Right, I see. But what about the correctness of my calculations and solutions?

Comment: Fix the $b$ typo and other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stationary points are correct.

In $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ the function $f$ has local minima and in $(-2,-1)$ and $(-1,-2)$ the function $f$ has local maxima (hessian matrix !)

Comment: The OP did not mention $(-1,-2)$ !